# Semantic UI change class inside css - Datatable Jquery Api

Tags: css, datatables, semantic-ui

I have a drop down button with already having css style as

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
  float: right;
}
```

this style applies simple dropdown floating at right side.

This is datatable jquery Api which renders style automatically. I am working on semantic ui and I want to apply this class `class="selection ui dropdown"`

What should I do to apply this class and where?